# Android NDK debugging: armeabi-v7a not working

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-ndk, cygwin

Eclipse / Cygwin

NDK 8c

Building a shared library

I can't get gdbserver to start anymore after switching to armeabi-v7a. I've searched online for hours but can't find a topic that deals specifically with armeabi-v7a debugging issues.

I have no choice to switch to armeabi-v7a due to using a third party library which depends on it. Without it, I get these kind of errors:

```
D:\TEMP\ccnnGAqD.s:10427: Error: selected processor does not support Thumb mode `ldrex r6,[r3]'
D:\TEMP\ccnnGAqD.s:10429: Error: selected processor does not support Thumb mode `strex r4,r5,[r3]'
```

It was all working fine before with 'armeabi', using this setup: http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/

The only change I've made is to add this to Application.mk:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

At the very bottom of the shared library Android.mk I added this:

```
$(info TARGET_ARCH     = $(TARGET_ARCH))
$(info TARGET_ARCH_ABI = $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI))
$(info TARGET_ABI      = $(TARGET_ABI))
```

which outputs the following:

```
TARGET_ARCH     = arm
TARGET_ARCH_ABI = armeabi-v7a
TARGET_ABI      = android-14-armeabi-v7a
```

I've uninstalled the app using

```
adb uninstall com.example.game
```

AndroidManifest.xml does have the android:debuggable="true" property.

Done a "clean all" in Eclipse, and manually deleted the ./libs and ./obj folders. Then, ndk-build outputs to the right folders (obj/local/armeabi-v7a and libs/armeabi-v7a), and obj/local/armeabi and libs/armeabi **do not exist.**

However, here's what happens when I run ndk-gdb:

```
user@MACHINENAME /cygdrive/e/projects/game
$ ndk-gdb-eclipse --force --verbose
Android NDK installation path: /cygdrive/e/projects/sdks/android-ndk
Using default adb command: /cygdrive/e/projects/sdks/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
ADB version found: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31
Using ADB flags:
Using auto-detected project path: .
Found package name: com.example.game
ABIs targetted by application: armeabi
Device API Level: 15
Device CPU ABIs: armeabi-v7a armeabi
Compatible device ABI: armeabi
Using gdb setup init: ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
Using toolchain prefix: /cygdrive/e/projects/sdks/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
Using app out directory: ./obj/local/armeabi
Found debuggable flag: true
ERROR: Could not find gdbserver binary under ./libs/armeabi
   This usually means you modified your AndroidManifest.xml to set
   the android:debuggable flag to 'true' but did not rebuild the
   native binaries. Please call 'ndk-build' to do so,
   *then* re-install to the device!
```

Notice the "ABIs targetted by application" using the wrong 'armeabi'. Here's the relevant part of ndk-gdb:

```
get_build_var ()
{
    if [ -z "$GNUMAKE" ] ; then
        GNUMAKE=make
    fi
    $GNUMAKE --no-print-dir -f $ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/build/core/build-local.mk -C $PROJECT DUMP_$1 | tail -1
}

APP_ABIS=`get_build_var APP_ABI`
if [ "$APP_ABIS" != "${APP_ABIS%%all*}" ] ; then
# replace first "all" with all available ABIs
  ALL_ABIS=`get_build_var NDK_ALL_ABIS`
  APP_ABIS_FRONT="${APP_ABIS%%all*}"
  APP_ABIS_BACK="${APP_ABIS#*all}"
  APP_ABIS="${APP_ABIS_FRONT}${ALL_ABIS}${APP_ABIS_BACK}"
fi
log "ABIs targetted by application: $APP_ABIS"
```

I clearly set APP_ABI to armeabi-v7a in Application.mk, so is this a bug in the NDK? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried to run `ndk-build DUMP_APP_ABI` for your project?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in clean-room scenario? I.e., use command line to `ndk-build`, and immediately after that run ndk-gdb?

Comment: There are 2 issues. First, I trigger ndk-build with NDK_APPLICATION_MK=config/<buildConfig>/Application.mk (this is why DUMP_APP_ABI worked properly). However, ndk-gdb only looks in jni/Application.mk (doesn't exist) so was using a default $NDK/build/core/default-application.mk and defaulting to 'armeabi'. Second, there doesn't seem to be a way to override NDK_APPLICATION_MK in ndk-gdb as there is with ndk-build. The only quick solution I can think of is to add jni/Application.mk and specify "APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a"

Comment: So, well, this is a small piece of information that was missing... When I asked you to run `ndk-build DUMP_APP_ABI` I did not expect you to silently add other parameters to this command ;-)

Comment: Is your `config/<buildConfig>/Application.mk` a one-liner? Is there some logic in `Android.mk` that depends on `<buildConfig>`? You should probably inform your `ndk-gdb` about the current `<buildConfig>`...

Comment: config/<buildConfig>/Application.mk defines APP_PLATFORM, APP_CFLAGS, APP_OPTIM, APP_STL, APP_ABI and a custom MY_BUILD_CONFIG (per config). All the Android.mk files use MY_BUILD_CONFIG as a suffix to module/library names. How can I inform ndk-gdb about the <buildConfig>, other than my current solution of adding jni/Application.mk? get_build_var() doesn't pass along parameters that you called ndk-gdb with, so the makefile it invokes just uses defaults for everything... right?

Comment: Try `ln -f -s config/<buildConfig>/Application.mk jni/Application.mk && ndk-gdb`

Comment: @AlexCohn, Hello!  I have a very similar situation. In my case, I have conditionals in my `Application.mk` file that check for a `BUILD_CONFIG` variable I pass when invoking `ndk-build`.  The build is working fine, however I can't debug the ARMEABI-V7A build.  If I invoke `ndk-build DUMP_APP_ABI`, I get `aremeabi` as a result. Any pointers are deeply appreciated!

Comment: @sgorozco: I am afraid I cannot help with this. Something is wrong in your logics that decides to report `DUMP_APP_ABI`=`armeabi`. What I did in a similar situation, I had a conditional include in my `Application.mk` that forced `APP_ABI` to be whatever was written in the included file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I configured eclipse following [this article](http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/).
Then I change from `armeabi` to `armeabi-v7a`. Then I couldn't debug.

I fixed this issue:
1) You must fix the folders in "Debug configurations"

- Main tab change `...obj/local/armeabi/app_process to ...obj/local/armeabi-v7a/app_process`
- Debugger tab change `...obj/local/armeabi/gdb2.setup to obj/local/armeabi-v7a/gdb2.setup`
- Debugger tab change `.../toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gdb to toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gdb`

2) May be this is workaround but it works. In "Debug configurations" `->Debugger->Shared Libraries add <project path>/obj/local/armeabi-v7a` and check "Load shared library symbols automatically"