# Cannot stat `./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup': No such file or directory when running ndk-gdb

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I have two projects on [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), one produce so and the other is an [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) application which use it. I am trying to debug the native code in the so.

Using the guide *[Using Eclipse for Android C/C++ Debugging](http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/)* after starting my project and running [NDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#Native_development_kit), I am getting the following error.

> cannot stat `./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup': No such file or directory when running ndk-gdb

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give much info, so I have to make assumptions.

That tutorial is set up for 'armeabi' but your error contains armeabi-v7a, so you probably have an ABI mismatch.

Your Application.mk is probably missing the following:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

See this post if you're using a custom Application.mk via NDK_APPLICATION_MK: [Android NDK debugging: armeabi-v7a not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591076/android-ndk-debugging-armeabi-v7a-not-working)

Also, your error contains gdb.setup whereas the tutorial uses gdb2.setup. Make sure you're using the file that ndk-gdb-eclipse generates.

On a side note, I don't recommend using gdb2.setup as this just confuses things. Your ndk-gdb-eclipse should output gdb.setup with line 704 commented out in ndk-gdb-eclipse (as of NDK r8c)

```
#echo "target remove :$DEBUG_PORT" >> $GDBSETUP
```

Comment: thank your for your answer but info like what can be useful ? 
app_abi is initialized right and gdb.setup is not bing generated since line 701 is producing the error mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

If ndk-gdb says it can't find "./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup", first try to check if this file exists. From the same location in which you run ndk-gdb, can you see this file? If not you may be running from the wrong location.